# ¿Cómo se pronuncia RAE?

Tags: pronunciación, rae

En el lenguaje hablado, ¿cómo se pronuncia las siglas RAE (Real Academia Española)? ¿Es con letras separadas, como si fuera una palabra unida, o algo más?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Esto es lo que dice el DPD sobre [la pronunciación de las siglas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=sigla):

> **2. Tipos de siglas según su lectura**
>
> a) Hay siglas que se leen tal como se escriben, las cuales reciben
>   también el nombre de acrónimos (→ acrónimo): ONU, OTAN, láser, ovni.
>   Muchas de estas siglas acaban incorporándose como sustantivos al
>   léxico común. Cuando una sigla está compuesta solo por vocales, cada
>   una de ellas se pronuncia de manera independiente y conserva su acento
>   fonético: OEA (Organización de Estados Americanos) se pronuncia
>   [ó-é-á].
>
> b) Hay siglas cuya forma impronunciable obliga a leerlas con deletreo:
>   FBI [éfe-bé-í], DDT [dé-dé-té], KGB [ká-jé-bé]. Integrando las vocales
>   necesarias para su pronunciación, se crean a veces, a partir de estas
>   siglas, nuevas palabras: elepé (de LP, sigla del ingl. long play
>   ‘larga duración’).
>
> c) Hay siglas que se leen combinando ambos métodos: CD-ROM
>   [se-de-rrón, ze-de-rrón] (sigla del ingl. Compact Disc Read-Only
>   Memory ‘disco compacto de solo lectura’). También en este caso pueden
>   generarse palabras a partir de la sigla: cederrón.

Resumiendo:

- si se puede leer, se lee
- si no se puede leer o son todo vocales, se deletrea
- a veces, se mezcla lectura con deletreo.

Answer (score 4):

Esta respuesta no tiene referencias, es en base a mi experiencia

Yo siempre la he escuchado y pronunciado como si fuese una sola palabra: RAE

**NO** como siglas, "erre" "a" "e".

Escuchalo tu mismo:

Answer (score 3):

Al decir verdad, yo no supe de la existencia de las siglas RAE hasta que me cambiê de país y necesitê un diccionario (gracias Google!). En mi país siempre se la nombró con su nombre completo: Real Academia Española :-)

Answer (score 2):

En general, al menos así ha sido en mi experiencia, en español nunca se leen acrónimos con las letras sino como una sóla palabra.

Comment: A menos que los acrónimos no tengan vocales, ahí se leen con letras separadas.

Comment: @dusan O que sean ilegibles. Me viene a la mente el PSOE, que tiene vocales, pero que, hasta donde se, no se pronuncia como una palabra.

Comment: @jachguate Sí se pronuncia como una palabra, no se lee "Pe ese o e" se lee "pesoe"

Comment: @dusan O no tengan consonantes (EEUU, AAA, etc)