# ¿«Con base en» o «En base a»?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, locuciones

A diario escucho gente expresarse tomando como referencia un fundamento o una justificación, la cual sustentan con *«con base en»* o en su caso *«en base a»*, por ejemplo:

> Con base en el artículo constitucional 12,345, a partir del año 2018 todo ciudadano extranjero podrá obtener la nacionalidad llenado el formato XYZ...

O bien,

> En base al artículo constitucional 12,345, a partir del año 2018 todo ciudadano extranjero podrá obtener la nacionalidad llenado el formato XYZ...

Lo cual me causa una duda impresionante. Si bien la primera referencia se lee y se escucha un tanto más coherente que la segunda, no estoy seguro de si la segunda de igual forma sería válida.

Según la [Academia Mexicana de la Lengua](http://www.academia.org.mx/espin/Detalle?id=360), lo correcto es *«con base en»*:

> La forma correcta es *con base en* y significa ‘con apoyo o fundamento en’.

Pero no es una fuente certificada.

Mi pregunta es: ¿cuál sería el argumento para definir si alguna de las dos formas es la correcta? O, en caso de que ambas sean válidas, ¿qué contexto determina usar una o la otra?

Comment: Otro ejemplo sería la primer sentencia de [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/3139/14481)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El **Diccionario panhispánico de dudas** recoge en el artículo [**base**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=base) (énfasis mío)

> 3. **con base en**. Precede a la expresión del lugar en el que se concentran instalaciones o equipos, generalmente militares, y que sirve de punto de partida para las distintas operaciones: *«La aviación “nacional”, con base en el aeródromo de Tablada, se adueñó del aire»*. En el primer tercio del siglo XX comenzó a usarse, en el lenguaje jurídico, con el sentido de ‘con apoyo o fundamento en’: *«De parte de los detractores del Almirante, se sostiene, con base en testimonios que figuran ...»*. De ahí ha pasado a otros ámbitos y está hoy bastante extendido, más en América que en España: *«Aquí vemos aparecer, con base en los estudios del astrónomo ... »*. **No hay razones lingüísticas para censurar su empleo en estos casos**, pues la noción de ‘apoyo o fundamento’ está presente en la palabra base, y las preposiciones con y en están bien utilizadas; no obstante, en el uso culto se prefieren otras fórmulas más tradicionales, como *sobre la base de, en función de, basándose en, a partir de, de acuerdo con, según*, etc. **Sí es censurable la locución de sentido equivalente Ⓧ*en base a***, en la que las preposiciones *en* y *a* no están justificadas: Ⓧ*«La petición se hizo en base a investigaciones policiales españolas»*. Podría tratarse de un calco del italiano *in base a*, única lengua de nuestro entorno en la que se documenta —desde finales del siglo XIX— esta locución, ya que en inglés se dice *on the basis of* y en francés *sur la base de*.
>
> 4. **en base a**. → 3.
>
> 5. **sobre la base de**. → 3.

En resumen:
 - **"con base en": correcto**, pero en el uso culto se prefieren otras fórmulas más tradicionales
 - **"en base a": incorrecto**
 - **"sobre la base de": correcto**

Comment: si "en base en" o "en base a" es incorrecto, entonces "basandome en" tambien seria incorrecto ?, o preguntar " en que te basas" es incorrecto y lo correcto es "con que te basas" ?

Answer (score 1):

La [Fundación del Español Urgente](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/con-base-en-mejor-que-en-base-a/), al igual que el artículo del Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas citado por @iznogud, nos recomienda evitar ambas formas; pero dice que es común oír "en base a" hoy día, y "**su empleo no puede censurarse**":

> La construcción *con base en* resulta preferible a la variante *en base
>   a,* aunque esta ya se encuentra muy extendida en el uso y su empleo no
>   puede censurarse.